# Should I worry to close db connection while connecting cloudant db from nodejs using cloudant module?

Tags: node.js, cloudant, dbconnection

I am connecting to cloudant using "cloudant" module in nodejs (npm install --save cloudant). Below is the code to initiate the db connection variable and then to use it.

```
//instantiate a cloudant var with the cloudant url. The url has id, password in it.
cloudant = require('cloudant')(dbCredentials.url);

//set the middleware with the db name
db = cloudant.use(dbCredentials.dbName);

//use the db variable to insert data into the db
function(req){

  db.insert({
     name:req.name,
     age:req.age
   },id,function(err,doc){
         ....
   });
};
```

Should I be worrying about closing the connection after I use db variable? It does not make sense to me since we are not using any connection pool here. To me we are simply instantiating the db variable with the endpoint, credentials and db name. Later we are calling the cloudant resources as ReST APIs. I am slightly confused here and dont think we need to do any close connection (which in fact means nothing but nullifying the cloudant variable). Can please share any comments, whether I am wrong or right? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the Cloudant library uses the default Node.js connection pooling so it will respect the server's "Keep-Alive" instruction, but is nothing that you need to worry about. Simply keep making Cloudant library function calls and the library will make HTTP connections when required - reusing existing connections when necessary, creating new ones in other cases.

Comment: Thanks Glynn for your answer. This explains what I was looking for.